# SOLVED - Laravel 5.8 Save file and image in another project and retrieve it

Tags: laravel, image, file, shared

i have two project in laravel 5.8.
First in sub1.domain.com
Second in sub2.domain.com

With sub2 i save images and files.
I need to view the image and files from sub2 and sub1.

Where is the best directory store for sharing the image and files ?

I have a shared hosting.

Thanks.

UPDATE - SOLVED

```
I have changed my filestystem config in this mode:

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            // 'root' => public_path() . '/uploads',
            'root' => '/home/xxx/www',
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

Now the file is stored in "public_html" of my "website.com" on my hosting for every subdomain.

Thanks everybody.

Comment: I recommend you using Digital Ocean Spaces / Amazon S3. https://medium.com/light-it/digital-ocean-spaces-with-laravel-ddddf81a32cb

Comment: Thank you but i can't use it :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs state](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#the-public-disk)

> The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly
>   accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and
>   stores these files in `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible from
>   the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to
>   `storage/app/public`

Assuming all your images & files will be publicly accessible, follow those instructions.

Then, instead of using `asset('storage/file.txt')` to print out the publicly accessible url, you could use a value from your `.env` file to get the path, which would be something like `"https://sub2.domain.com/images/"` and then just append your file name.

Or [write a custom helper method](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers) that allows you to specify the subdomain, something like `custom_asset('storage/file.txt', 'sub2')`

Answer (score 0):

you can upload in public folder as symbolic link is hard hard to make cpanel

modify ur

```php
filesystems.php
in 
'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('app/public/uploads'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/uploads',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

in above linke 
ur upload path will be

```sh
public/uploads
and 
 \Storage::url('example.png')  to get full image url
```